# Testcases are not getting publish on JIRA while using Zephyr with jenkins although zapi installed with JIRA - specific for Cucumber framework

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, jira-plugin, jira-zephyr

Already done with below mentioned steps 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Zephyr+For+Jira+Test+Management+Plugin

Testcases are not getting publish on JIRA while using Zephyr with jenkins although zapi installed with JIRA - specific for Cucumber framework

> Test cycle is getting generated but no test-cases are publishing on those test cycles

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved !!

This was admin right issue, user need to get full administrator rights for their project to get it done completely via automation.